# how to match uncertain numbers without special words before them with js regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

For Example. I want to get the numbers without 'the' or 'abc' or 'he' before them;

1. the89   (no match)
2. thisis90   (match 90)
3. iknow89999   (match 89999)
4. getthe984754 (no match)
5. abc58934(no match)
6. he759394 (no match)

I try to use this `(?<!(the|abc|he))[0-9]+` , but failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex with negative lookbehind:

```sh
(?<!t?he|abc|\d)\d+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WeWaE0/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!`: Start negative lookbehind, to fail when we get any of:

  - `t?he`: `the` or `he`
  - `|`: OR
  - `abc`: `abc`
  - `|`: OR
  - `\d`: a digit
- `)`: End negative lookbehind
- `\d+`: Match 1+ digits

Answer (score 1):

you could use [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
/(?<=\s)\d+/g
```

```js
const data = [
  "the89",
  "this is 90",
  "i like the60",
  "i know 89999",
  "get the984754",
];

const matches = data.map((s) => s.match(/(?<=\s)\d+/g));

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: I update the question，please have a look.

Comment: what is wrong with my regex  (?<!(the|abc|he))[0-9]+